# scala slick 2.0.2 cannot automatic map to custom class

Tags: scala, mapping, slick

I'm starting to play with Slick and i can't figure out how to get results of query mapped on my custom case class.
Here's my code:

```
package main.scala.model.Tree

import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._

case class SlickNode(id : Long, parentId : Long, stateString : String) 
    extends AbstractNode{}

object SlickNode {
    val nodes = TableQuery[SlickNodes]
    def findById(x : Long) : SlickNode = nodes.filter(_.id == x).first
    def findByParentId(x : Long) : Iterable[SlickNode] = nodes.filter(_.parentId == x).list

}

class SlickNodes(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Long, Long, String)](tag, "NODES") {
    def id = column[Long]("NODE_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def parentId = column[Long]("PARENT")
    def stateString = column[String]("STATE")
    def * = (id, parentId, stateString) <> ((SlickNode.apply _).tupled , SlickNode.unapply)
}
```

What I expected was the automatic conversion from (Long, Long, String) to SlickNode as stated in the * definition.
Am I missing something? 
Thank you in advance.
Kind Regards

************* EDIT *************
I think the problem is deeper in my code. 
When i try to compile it I get this error:

```
[error] No matching Shape found.
[error] Slick does not know how to map the given types.
[error] Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection. Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List).
[error]   Required level: scala.slick.lifted.ShapeLevel.Flat
[error]      Source type: scala.slick.lifted.MappedProjection[main.scala.model.Tree.SlickNode,(Long, Long, String)]
[error]    Unpacked type: (Long, Long, String)
[error]      Packed type: Any
[error]   def * = (id, parentId, stateString) <> ((SlickNode.apply _).tupled , SlickNode.unapply)
[error]                                       ^
```

Comment: I think the problem is deeper in my code. When i try to compile it I get this error:
No matching Shape found.
Slick does not know how to map the given types.
Possible causes: T in Table[T] does not match your * projection. Or you use an unsupported type in a Query (e.g. scala List).
Required level: scala.slick.lifted.ShapeLevel.Flat
Source type: scala.slick.lifted.MappedProjection[main.scala.model.Tree.SlickNode,(Long, Long, String)]
Unpacked type: (Long, Long, String)
Packed type: Any
def * = (id, parentId, stateString) <> ((SlickNode.apply _).tupled , SlickNode.unapply)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are extending a table of triple, not a table of `SlickNodeRow`:

```
class AbstractNode

case class SlickNodeRow(id : Long, parentId : Long, stateString : String) extends AbstractNode

object SlickNode {
  val nodes = TableQuery[SlickNodes]
  def findById(x : Long)(implicit s: Session): Option[SlickNodes#TableElementType] = nodes.filter(_.id === x).firstOption
  def findByParentId(x : Long) : Iterable[SlickNodeRow] = nodes.filter(_.parentId == x).list
}

class SlickNodes(tag: Tag) extends Table[SlickNodeRow](tag, "NODES") {
                                             * here   
  def id = column[Long]("NODE_ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def parentId = column[Long]("PARENT")
  def stateString = column[String]("STATE")
  def * = (id, parentId, stateString) <> ((SlickNodeRow.apply _).tupled , SlickNodeRow.unapply)
}
```

And the projections function doesn't know how to map a triple to the `SlickNodeRow` case class. If you want to return triple your code should look like this:

```
class Suppliers(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, String, String)](tag, "SUPPLIERS") {
  def id = column[Int]("SUP_ID", O.PrimaryKey)
  def name = column[String]("SUP_NAME")
  def street = column[String]("STREET")
  def * = (id, name, street)
}
val suppliers = TableQuery[Suppliers]
```

[As shown here](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.2/migration.html?highlight=projection), the projection doesn't return a case class, but a triple instead. Probably you could write your projection method in a way that it would return a `SlickNodeRow` from a triple, I'm not sure though.

Comment: I was missing it so bad... I knew there was something like that.. but can't figure it out... Thank you very much!

Comment: I added an example of how to return triple if you don't want to use case classes.